# Configuring the IBM JDK Version JAVA_HOME not working from java 1.6 to 1.7/1.8 on IBM i 7.4

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, java-home

We are trying to change java version 1.6 to 1.7 or 1.8, in an System i 7.4. as follow.

Our production system has java 1.6 verion bby default.

**java -version**

java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr16fp25-20160422_01(SR16 FP25)
)
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 OS/400 ppc-32 jvmap3260sr16fp25-20
160422_01 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20160413_299433
JIT  - r9_20160328_114196
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20160413_1159_B299433)
JCL  - 20160421_01

**echo $PATH**

/usr/bin:.:/QOpenSys/usr/bin

I used an CLLE. to change the version as follow:

````
DCL        VAR(&PGM) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(36) VALUE('java +
               -jar “/MyDirectory/MyObj.jar"')

RMVENVVAR  ENVVAR(JAVA_HOME)
MONMSG     MSGID(CPF0000)   

ADDENVVAR  ENVVAR(JAVA_HOME) +                           
             VALUE('/QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk70+
             /32bit')   

STRQSH CMD(&PGM)

RETURN

ENDPGM

// end CLLE ```

But after running the CLLE code, still Java version 1.6.

However in the QA System it got changed after running de CLLE program.

Any ideas?

V7R2M0

QMODEL = 41A

5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  IBM Developer Kit para Java
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 6 32 bits          
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 6 64 bits          
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 7 32 bits  
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 7 64 bits  

Best regards.
````

Comment: Are you using V7.2 or v7.4? It looks like V7.2 based on the V7R2M0. I wouldn't expect Java 1.6 to be available for v7.4 since support for it was removed at v7.3.

Comment: it is V7R2M0 operating system. But the default Java installed is 1.6, and it also has Java 1.7 and 1.8 compatible. As show in my post. 
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  IBM Developer Kit para Java
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 6 32 bits          
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 6 64 bits          
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 7 32 bits  
5770JV1   *COMPATIBLE  Java SE 7 64 bits

Comment: The default JVM is selected differently for each server you are trying to use. When you are just using the java command, and setting environment variables in a CL, that is only for the job in which you call the CL. We need more information on how you are calling the CL (interactive/batch) how you are looking for the java version, etc.

Comment: We try both, Batch and inteeractive , both procedures work in the QA server, but neigther work in the production environment. The CLEE is listed above.